# retrieving output of a bash file ran from python subprocess

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, popen

I have to run a bash file through python for a Django webapp project but I cannot retrieve the output of the bash file (which I really need since it needs to be displayed on a web page). here is the code:

in my python file:

```
import subprocess 


output = subprocess.Popen(['bash', 'countingbash.sh', "hello", "world"])
print (output)
```

in countingbash.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
file="$@"
for f in $file
    do
    echo "Argument is $f"

done
```

I need to capture the output since it needs to be displayed later on in a webpage. If I run the .py file, the output I get is not what the output should be by running a bash file.  The output looks like this:

```
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x102cab290>
```

whereas it should be:

```
Argument is hello
Argument is world
```

If I run the file alone without writing print(output), the editor shows the output but how do i capture it?

Answer (score 1):

This modification should give you correct output , I have opened stdout pipe and converted the shell output from binary string.I have used absolute path to avoid any of the working directory problem as well :

```
output = subprocess.Popen(['bash', '/home/demo/test.sh', "hello", "world"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print (output.communicate()[0].decode('ascii'))
```